# Threads and static methods

Tags: java, multithreading

My questions is about Java.
Can several threads access a static method of a static class at the same time or can only one thread at a time executing the method?

If I use synchronized in the method header, only one thread can execute it at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can several threads access a static method of a static class at the same time or can only one thread at a time executing the method?

Yes, they can. Unless the method is `synchronized`, there is no constraint on the number of threads that can access that method.

> If I use synchronized in the method header, only one thread can execute it at a time?

Exactly. The "method header" `synchronized` keyword on static methods imposes a lock *on the class itself*, preventing other threads to enter.

```
public static synchronized void foo() {
    ...
}
```

is (almost) equivalent to

```
public static void foo() {
   synchronized(MyClass.class) {
      ...
   }
}
```